# UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri content

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, uri, android-permissions, file-permissions

I've got a activity/intent launcher, where the user can choose a directory from the external storage. After choosing a folder, the uri path is stored in sharedpreferences and the foldername is displayed in a textview:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> actResLauncher;
actResLauncher = registerForActivityResult(   new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),this);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);   
actResLauncher.launch(intent);


@Override
public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {

    int resultCode = result.getResultCode();
    Intent resultIntent = result.getData();

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && resultIntent != null) {

        Uri uri = resultIntent.getData();
        
        //Safe Uri "path" to shared preference
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getContext().getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.BACKUP, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(AppConstants.AUTOMATIC_BACKUP_FOLDER, uri.toString());
        editor.commit();
        
        //Display Folderdame on textview
        DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getContext(), uri);
        automaticBackupFolder.setText(documentFile.getName());
    )
}
```

This works like charm and the Uri can be restored from the Shared Preference Folder:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.BACKUP, MODE_PRIVATE);
DocumentFile sourceFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(getContext(), Uri.parse(prefs.getString(AppConstants.AUTOMATIC_BACKUP_FOLDER)));
automaticBackupFolder.setText(sourceFile.getName()); //Throws UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri content exception
```

Using the `DocumentFile` object I can get the parent file, check if folder exsists etc. and that works perfectly.
However, the issue is that when **recreating the fragment** (e.g by rotating the phone), the function `getPath()` throws the following exception: `UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri content`

This error does not occur when displaying the Folder Name in the onActivityResult function, it appears when the Uri gets stored in the Shared Preferences Folder **AND** the fragment is created again (e.g. rotating phone)

What might the issue be?
Is it maybe that after recreating the fragment, the app loses permissions to view the folder name?

Comment: You say that the function getPath() throws an exception, but there's call to getPath() in your code. So it's hard to figure out what you're referring to. DocumentFile doesn't have a getPath() method, AFAICT. Did you mean getName()?

Answer (score 2):

In `onActivityResult()`, when you get your `Uri`, call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in your `Uri`. Otherwise, [your access to the content is limited to whatever activity instance got the `Uri` and goes away entirely when your process is terminated](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: unfourtantly this solution did not work :/ maybe its cause its a folder and not a file?

Comment: @igodie: `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` is for document `Uri` values. Try `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()`.

Comment: hmm using fromTree uri I receive the following error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://media/external/file/164443 using fromSingleUri it turns out I receive a number as filename: 164443. The getname() method returns the corrent name in onactivityresult but the number when rotating the phone. maybe the filename is only temporary and it has nothing to do with the additional rights?